# Django : make_aware expects a naive datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, timezone

I started to work on a project built with Django and I can't figure something out.

I have in my settings.py :

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

In my models.py, I have date fields like this :

```
#...
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
#...
```

And my urls are defined like this in urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^api/catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
    url(r'^api/logs/', include('logs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And in catalog/urls.py :

```
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
# ...
projects_router = NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'projects', lookup='project', trailing_slash=False)
projects_router.register(r'requests', ProjectRequestViewSet, base_name='project-requests')
# ...
requests_router = NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'requests', lookup='request', trailing_slash=False)
requests_router.register(r'statuses', RequestStatusViewSet, base_name='request-statuses')
# ...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(projects_router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(requests_router.urls)),
    url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^token-auth', views.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

And since I have updated to Django 1.9.1, I have the following warnings :

> .\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py:37:
>
> RemovedInDjango110Warning: You haven't defined a TEMPLATES setting.
>   You must do so before upgrading to Django 1.10. Otherwise Django will
>   be unable to load templates. "unable to load templates.",
>   RemovedInDjango110Warning)
>
> .\balrog\urls.py:8: RemovedInDjango110Warning:
>
> django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in
>   Django 1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of
>   django.conf.urls.url() instances instead. url(r'^admin/',
>   include(admin.site.urls)),

(That's not the main point of this question, but any help to remove these warnings is also appreciated.)

And whenever I'm trying to get an object with a date field with the API, I get the following error :

> ValueError: make_aware expects a naive datetime, got 2016-01-15 17:18:44.258843+00:00

So this error doesn't occur if `USE_TZ` is set to `False` but that's not ideal, I need it to be `True`.

Another way to remove this error is to edit `.\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py`
And change this make_aware function :

```
def make_aware(value, timezone=None, is_dst=None):
    """
    Makes a naive datetime.datetime in a given time zone aware.
    """
    if timezone is None:
        timezone = get_current_timezone()
    if hasattr(timezone, 'localize'):
        # This method is available for pytz time zones.
        return timezone.localize(value, is_dst=is_dst)
    else:
        # Check that we won't overwrite the timezone of an aware datetime.
        if is_aware(value):
            raise ValueError(
                "make_aware expects a naive datetime, got %s" % value)
        # This may be wrong around DST changes!
        return value.replace(tzinfo=timezone)
```

To this :

```
def make_aware(value, timezone=None, is_dst=None):
    """
    Makes a naive datetime.datetime in a given time zone aware.
    """
    if timezone is None:
        timezone = get_current_timezone()
    if hasattr(timezone, 'localize'):
        # This method is available for pytz time zones.
        return timezone.localize(value, is_dst=is_dst)
    else:
        return value
```

But that's not ideal neither.

Why is my make_aware function even called since the dates should already be aware and not naive with `USE_TZ` set to `True` ?

Btw, I'm using a SQLite database in case that's related (since sqlite use date field as string afaik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's actually, because some date in my database were manually inserted as a string and SQLite didn't make the difference, wiping the db and rebuilding it using Django ORM solved the issue.